# Does the sequence $x_0=12$ , $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1$ contain a prime?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

I wonder whether the sequence defined by $$x_0=12$$ $$x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1$$ for all non-negative integers $n$ contains a prime number.

The following table shows from left to right : The index $n$ , the number of digits of $x_n$ and the smallest prime factor of $x_n$.For $n=17$, I did not find a prime factor so far.

```
? x=12;j=0;while(length(digits(x))<10^6,j=j+1;x=x^2+1;p=2;while(Mod(x,p)<>0,p=ne
xtprime(p+1));print(j,"   ",length(digits(x)),"   ",p))
1   3   5
2   5   2
3   9   13
4   18   2
5   35   733
6   70   2
7   139   5
8   277   2
9   554   1536673
10   1107   2
11   2214   13
12   4427   2
13   8854   5
14   17707   2
15   35413   13
16   70825   2
```

As we can see, a prime of the desired form must have more than $140\ 000$ digits. The smallest prime factor of $x_9$ is already large and the smallest prime factor of $x_{17}$ will be considerably larger (I currently search for a prime factor)

> - Is $x_{17}$ prime ?
> - Does the sequence contain a prime ?

UPDATE :

This is a somewhat modified program to determine the indices $n$ for which $x_n$ has no prime factor belo $10^7$

```
? for(k=1,50,p=1;gef=0;while((gef==0)*(p<10^7),p=nextprime(p+1);s=12;for(j=1,k,s
=lift(Mod(s^2+1,p)));if(s==0,gef=1));if(gef==0,print1(k," ")))
17 33
?
```

Since $x_{33}$ is already huge , the only hope is $x_{17}$, but if I did not make an error using the factordb-database, $x_{17}$ should be composite.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, by $x_n^2$ you mean $(x_n)^2$, right?

Comment: @DavidR. Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Where did this problem originate?

Comment: I played around the sequences $x_0=a$ , $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1$ with $a$ some start value and noticed that we do not get a prime fast in the case $a=12$. $a=9$ seems to be a similar hard case

Comment: what remainders on division by 6 do all primes above 3 have to be? ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee wouldn't that just mean that $n$ must be odd for $x_n$ to be prime?  The way I see it by induction $x_n\equiv 1 \mod 6$ if $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$ so $x_n \equiv 1+1 = 2\mod 6$ if $n \equiv 2 \mod 4$. so $x_n\equiv 2^1 + 1 \equiv -1 \mod 6$ if $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and $x_n \equiv (-1)^2 + 1 \equiv 2 \mod 6$ if $n \equiv 0 \mod 4$.

Comment: I was trying to limit the cases to look at @fleablood. it eliminates some possibilities. also as 2 leads to -1 and -1 leads to 2 your analysis is not quite right , your answer is. but all primes in this sequence unless the first term is prime will be -1 mod 6.

Comment: If the index is even, then the number is a multiple of $2$. If the index is $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, then the number is a multiple of $5$. If the index is $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then the number is a multiple of $13$. If the index is $\equiv 4\pmod{7}$, then the number is a multiple of $41$. That narrows down the indices you have to check a bit more.

Comment: you can also use PARI/GP to figure out that only indices that are 3 or 5 mod 7 can be prime because they aren't coprime to 120 otherwise.

Comment: With my modified program , I also checked the sequence with start-value $9$. The only prime-candidates are $x_6$ and $x_{46}$, but $601888249$ divides $x_6$ , and $x_{46}$ is huge.

Comment: Using all primes under $200$ narrows it down to only a few indices $\bmod 4284$, and I can post the list somewhere if someone thinks it'll be helpful. But I don't think this approach will be useful as primality testing for even $x_17$ will be pretty much impossible.

Comment: most of what we've been discussing are sieving indexes, you might also try the polynomial remainder theorem,  which may let you use the even values you are getting every second term. it says that  in a polynomial every value taken on by the polynomial divides infinitely many more terms further along. if you count it as a function f(x)=x^2+1 for example you get that all x values that all of a certain type get eliminated but then you have to map that onto your iterative function.

Comment: Raising the trial-division-limit to $10^8$, the only candidate upto $n=100$ for start value $12$ is $x_{17}$. $65274089$ divides $x_{33}$.

Comment: And with start value $9$, the smallest candidate is $x_{54}$ which is definitely too big for a primilaty test

Comment: an example of how it would work is that x^2+1=2 for x=1  this value ( by parity argument even) divides into every second term. x^2+1= 5 for x=2 which by pigeonhole principle then divides into every fifth term at very least. if a prime p doesn't divide one of the first r terms ( even iterated) then it never can because by then the modular remainders must start to repeat.

Comment: r should be replaced with p in the previous comment sorry.

Comment: Trial division is done up through $10^9$ - no primes yet.

Comment: From the table it looks like factorisation gets difficult when the index is of the form $2^n+1$. Can somebody give an argument why that is (if it remains so)?

Comment: $x_{17}$ is composite (tested using PFGW).

Comment: @pietfermat How did you input the number ?

Comment: @Peter I used a text file. I Calculated the number with arbitrary precision calculation program and saved the result as text in a file.

Comment: This looks similar to the issue of finding Fermat primes, that is, of the form $2^{2^n}+1$. They satisfy$ x_{n+1} = x_n^2-2x_n$ instead. Because your sequence grows very fast a similar heuristic argument can be given for why one expects it to have only finitely many primes, and since the first few ones are composite maybe we should expect none.

Comment: does rewriting $x_n^2+1$ as $(x_n-1)(x_n+1)+2$ help? Going back to @ user451844 I feel like there is something fruitful to come about with this rewriting of the problem and using a @user451844 I feel like there's an approach using a sieve that may show that there are no primes in this set possibly using strong induction.

Comment: @jakemckenzie Since small prime factors apparently are not forced, I highly doubt that strong induction helps here.